Change the order status to processing
I am using the sales_order_shipment_save_after event and in that i want to set the order status to processing because magento set the status to complete once the shipment is submited but I want to keep the status processing after shipment also.

Making it happen the programming way is good, but not having to rely on coding is even better. You can change the status to processing or any other you want using the Magefan Order Editor for Magento.

in your observer try the following code..and add necessary condition based on your requirement
  <?php
namespace Vendor\OrderStatus\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class KeepOrderStatusProcessing implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
     
        $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();

       
        $order = $shipment->getOrder();

       
        $order->setStatus('processing');

       
        $order->save();
    }
}


I believe you are using an online payment method and upon an order being placed on the website, the order status is already in the Processing status.
That is why when you submit the shipment, the order status adjusts to Complete.
However, you can use Event Observer to set the Order status as processing on shipment submission. You can put a condition that your logic should be applied the first time (when the shipment is created. Not updated.)
